# Breaking a number to primes - Why does this code never stop?

Tags: python, primes

```
def breaktoprimes(x):
    primefactors = []
    if x==1:
        primefactors.append(1)
    y=1
    while y<=x or x!=1:
        if(x%y==0):
            primefactors.append(y)
            x=x/y
            y=1
        else:
            y=y+1
    return primefactors
```

So basically what i am trying to do with this, is to fill the list "primefactors" with the prime factors of x. However, no matter what i enter, the code just runs and runs, and after some time, returns with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    breaktoprimes(15)
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 8, in breaktoprimes
    primefactors.append(y)
MemoryError
```

Basically what i intended the code to do is:

1. While y is smaller or equal to x and while x is not equal to one, which it should always apply to unless you enter a smaller number than 1 or x got divided by itself, in either case we are finished, we go on

   2. test if the division of x by y results in the remainder of 0. If it does, y is sure to be a prime factor of x since y is not bigger than x and, y can't be a multiplication of a prime since we have tested the smaller numbers already.
   3. If that didin't work, we add 1 to the value of y and try again

I have searched the web, but the solutions to this problem i have found are very different, so i haven't found any help in them. I have no idea where the problem in this code lies. I am a beginner in python with c# background and have coded for about a year now.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: 1 is not a prime number. You shouldn't include 1 in a list of prime factors.

Comment: additionally, that's a problem you could have solved easily by just adding a print x,y statement to your while loop, to monitor the progress.

Comment: @khelwood et al : True, 1 is a unit, neither prime nor composite. I suppose this function _could_ return [] if x==1 or x==0, but IMO returning [1] and [0] respectively in those cases is understandable. Of course, 1 should **certainly** not be included as a prime factor for other values of x!

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes the function could return `[]` for 1 and 0 (or raise an exception). That would have the benefit of not being incorrect.

Comment: @khelwood FWIW, the *nix `factor` command returns an empty list for arg of 0 or 1, but in my own code I like to distinguish between the cases, and don't want to throw an exception. To repeat, I'm **not** saying that 0 or 1 are prime, just that [1] and [0] are _reasonable_ outputs, and may be entirely appropriate, depending on what the rest of the program is doing. I guess if you wish to continue this discussion, we should take it to Chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All numbers are divisible by `1`. Choosing `1` as an initival value for `y` is not good choice.
2. Reset `y` to `1` should be gone (same reason for 1)

---

```
def breaktoprimes(x):
    primefactors = []
    if x == 1:
        primefactors.append(1)
    y = 2
    while y <= x or x != 1:
        if x % y == 0:
            primefactors.append(y)
            x = x / y
        else:
            y = y + 1
    return primefactors
```

Answer (score 2):

If `x=1` and `y=1` then `y<=x or x!=1` is true, and `x=x/y` sets `x` to 1, so both `x` and `y` will continue to be 1 and the loop will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code:

```
y=1
while y<=x or x!=1:
    if(x%y==0):
        primefactors.append(y)
        x=x/y
        y=1
```

`x%y` is `0`. Then `y` becomes `1` again. So the loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your x and y values are always remaining the same. So due to this your code runs in infinite loop.